# Avoiding loading hundreds of view controllers in a custom UIViewController container

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I've written a custom UIViewController container that acts similarly to Flipboard's pages. The user can swipe/tap through "pages" that are child view controllers. I feel I've written it well but am fearing that I will run into a scenario where there could be hundreds of child view controllers. I want to avoid loading all of those view controllers into memory (as they will all have UICollectionViews with lots of data).

Since there is a gesture interaction for swiping through the views, I need each "next" and "previous" view to be added to the container view and loaded so that it is visible if the user starts to swipe over another page.

How could I stop every single view controller's -viewDidLoad from happening so that each view controller can be loaded only when needed? Are there any "best practices" or example UIViewController containers out there where I could get some ideas on only loading the child controllers that are next/previous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you should have a container `UIViewController` and two `UIViewControllers` (like you said). One will be the next and the other one will be the previous. You can then keep a reference to both, and when you are about to go to the next ( for example ), you just update it, like:

```
- (void)updateViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withDataSource:(NSDictionary *)dataSource;
```

In the end you have 3 `UIViewControllers`. Other solutions are possible, and you can always have a look at GitHub for some inspiration, or CocoaControls.

Comment: My only issue is that when creating my controllers I need to be able to do something like -initWithControllers:(NSArray*)... Maybe I should change the structure to go off of an array of data and not the controllers? My only concern there though is that it breaks the idea of it simply being a container of controllers, it now becomes a view controller, unlike how UINavigationController simply handles the VC stack + transitions.

Comment: The transitions and the data source are different things. You can either allow each `UIViewController` (next and previous) to access the data source, or the container provide the data to them... (I would go with the first one.)

Comment: You got me going in the right direction! I changed how the view controllers are accessed. Instead of an array of controllers I have a data source asked for each view controller. This keeps the load of ViewControllers low to only the controllers that need to be created.